# Can I fetch data only once when using swr?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For example, I switch to different page using react router:

```
const Apage = () => {
    const { data, error } = useSWR('/a-data', fetcher);
    return (
        <div>{data}</div>
    );
};

const Bpage = () => {
    const { data, error } = useSWR('/b-data', fetcher);
    return (
        <div>{data}</div>
    );
};
```

With swr, I can get data immediately when I'm not the first time access the page.
But still, it calls the api to fetch data each time I access the page.

**Can I only fetch data once if I dont need to revalidate the data is stale or not?**

Comment: Look at state managements, for example Mobx is good for small projects

Comment: Yes, I used to use redux + saga to solve this problem, now I wonder if I can use swr do the exactly same thing.

Answer (score 21):

With [SWR 1.0.0](https://swr.vercel.app/blog/swr-v1), you can do this easily with the new `useSWRImmutable` hook:

```js
import useSWRImmutable from 'swr/immutable'

// ...
useSWRImmutable(key, fetcher, options)
```

When using this hook, all kinds of automatic revalidations will be disabled for it. If there is already cache existing, SWR will not send extra requests.

Docs: https://swr.vercel.app/docs/revalidation#disable-automatic-revalidations

Comment: can confirm this works.

Answer (score 14):

**SWR 0.3.8**

You should prevent automatic revalidation which is controlled by the next options:

```
{
  revalidateOnFocus: false,
  revalidateOnMount:false,
  revalidateOnReconnect: false,
  refreshWhenOffline: false,
  refreshWhenHidden: false,
  refreshInterval: 0,
}
```

According to the [documentation](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/revalidation) `refreshWhenOffline`, `refreshWhenHidden` and `refreshInterval` are disabled by default, so it's enough only to set:

```
{
  revalidateOnFocus: false,
  revalidateOnMount:false,
  revalidateOnReconnect: false,
}
```

This will restrict SWR from running the fetching method. However, you still need the first one run to get your data.

You may end up with something like this:

```
const useStaleSWR = (dataKey) => {
  const revalidationOptions = {
    revalidateOnMount: !cache.has(dataKey), //here we refer to the SWR cache
    revalidateOnFocus: false,
    revalidateOnReconnect: false,
  };

  return useSWR(dataKey, fetcher, revalidationOptions);
}
```

SWR cache is exposed since [0.2.0 version](https://github.com/vercel/swr/releases/tag/0.2.0-beta.0)

---

After all, I do not recommend using SWR for this purpose. SWR built to fetch data again. If you have static data - fetch once and store in session/local storage or define your own cache.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting how to use the `cache` been stuck there for an hour. I still think it's good to use SWR just for its caching management though...

Comment: it should be `revalidateOnMount: !cache.has(dataKey),`  in your example

Answer (score 3):

**Disable Automatic Revalidations**

Since version 1.0, SWR provides a helper hook useSWRImmutable to mark the resource as immutable:

```
import useSWRImmutable from 'swr/immutable'

// ...
useSWRImmutable(key, fetcher, options)
```

useSWR(key, fetcher, {
revalidateIfStale: false,
revalidateOnFocus: false,
revalidateOnReconnect: false
})

// equivalent to
useSWRImmutable(key, fetcher)

It has the same API interface as the normal ***useSWR*** hook. You can also do the same thing by disable the following revalidation options:

```
useSWR(key, fetcher, {
  revalidateIfStale: false,
  revalidateOnFocus: false,
  revalidateOnReconnect: false
})

// equivalent to
useSWRImmutable(key, fetcher)
```

The revalidateIfStale controls if SWR should revalidate when it mounts and there is stale data.

These 2 hooks above do the exact same thing. Once the data is cached, they will never request it again.

Answer (score 0):

`SWR` concept is based on `hooks`. That means it means to use with local state, not for global state like `mobx`/`redux`/etc. Of course you can use with global state via `React Context` by creating your custom context. But you will prefer to use `mobx`/`redux` instead right?

So this is a caching strategy. If you prefer cache in memory, use `mobx`/`redux`. Otherwise, store in `localStorage`/`cookie`/etc.

Answer (score 0):

Using this configuration makes the request called only once within an hour. If you need more time just increase the deduping interval.

```
 const { data, error } = useSWR('/api/get.json', fetcher, {
        dedupingInterval: 3600000,
        revalidateOnFocus: false,
        revalidateOnReconnect: false,
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the top component like this

App.tsx

```
const { mutate } = useFoo()

useEffect(() => { 
mutate()
}, [mutate])
```

useFoo.ts

```
const useFoo = () => useSWR(key, fetcher, {
  revalidateOnFocus: false,
  revalidateOnMount: false,
  revalidateOnReconnect: false,
  refreshWhenOffline: false,
  refreshWhenHidden: false,
  refreshInterval: 0,
})
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set `revalidateOnFocus` to `false` to prevent SWR from revalidating when the window comes back into view.

https://swr.vercel.app/docs/revalidation

Comment: `revalidateOnMount` and `revalidateOnReconnect` will still revalidate the data

Answer (score -1):

Just use **dedupingInterval**, like:

```
   const { data } = useSWR(
        `https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/breeds?api_key=51e7b5a4-3b54-4fdf-a61a-84b653d85f8a`,
        fetcher,
        {
            dedupingInterval: 1000000,
        }
    );
```

Comment: `dedupingInterval` doesn't prevent from running the fetching method